# $.cookie is not a function typeerror

Tags: jquery, html

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

```
TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$($.cookie("inputFocus")).focus()
```

Relevant line:

```
$($.cookie("inputFocus")).focus()
```

All jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#state").change(function () {
    this.form.submit();
})
$($.cookie("inputFocus")).focus()

$("#supplier_name").val($("#supplier_name").val());
$("#aircraft_type").val($("#aircraft_type").val());
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 600;  

$('#supplier_name').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#supplier_name').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#supplier_name"); 
});

$('#aircraft_type').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#aircraft_type').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#aircraft_type"); });
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

var state = GetQueryStringParams('state');
var supplier_name = GetQueryStringParams('supplier_name');
var aircraft_type = GetQueryStringParams('aircraft_type');

    if(supplier_name === "" && state === "any" && aircraft_type === "") {
            $('#clear').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    $("#clear").click(function() {
    if(state === "any") {
        $("#aircraft_type").val("");
        $("#supplier_name").val("");
    } else {
        $('#state option:selected').remove();
        $("#aircraft_type").val("");
        $("#supplier_name").val("");    
    }
    });

function doneTyping () {
    $("form").submit();
}

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) before this code snippet.

Comment: This Jquerry code plugin is deprecated, this is the good library : https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 11):

Including jquery file twice(multiple time) also gave same issue in my case.

Comment: For me jQuery was added more than once.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That error means exactly what it says: `$.cookie` does not exist.

jQuery core does not include anything related to cookies.  There are [several cookie libraries](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+cookie) that add a `cookie` function to `$`.  You need to add one to your page first.

Answer (score 0):

It means the library that's supposed to have that function is not loaded. But you can set a cookie using javascript, here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie