# How to set cookie for a dialog box in jquery?

Tags: jquery, cookies, dialog, box

```js
//----------jquery.cookie.js begins-------------
/*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.1
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2006, 2014 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
(function (factory) {
 if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  // AMD (Register as an anonymous module)
  define(['jquery'], factory);
 } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
  // Node/CommonJS
  module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
 } else {
  // Browser globals
  factory(jQuery);
 }
}(function ($) {

 var pluses = /\+/g;

 function encode(s) {
  return config.raw ? s : encodeURIComponent(s);
 }

 function decode(s) {
  return config.raw ? s : decodeURIComponent(s);
 }

 function stringifyCookieValue(value) {
  return encode(config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value));
 }

 function parseCookieValue(s) {
  if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
   // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape...
   s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
  }

  try {
   // Replace server-side written pluses with spaces.
   // If we can't decode the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
   // If we can't parse the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
   s = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
   return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
  } catch(e) {}
 }

 function read(s, converter) {
  var value = config.raw ? s : parseCookieValue(s);
  return $.isFunction(converter) ? converter(value) : value;
 }

 var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

  // Write

  if (arguments.length > 1 && !$.isFunction(value)) {
   options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

   if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
    var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
    t.setMilliseconds(t.getMilliseconds() + days * 864e+5);
   }

   return (document.cookie = [
    encode(key), '=', stringifyCookieValue(value),
    options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
    options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
    options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
    options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
   ].join(''));
  }

  // Read

  var result = key ? undefined : {},
   // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
   // in case there are no cookies at all. Also prevents odd result when
   // calling $.cookie().
   cookies = document.cookie ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [],
   i = 0,
   l = cookies.length;

  for (; i < l; i++) {
   var parts = cookies[i].split('='),
    name = decode(parts.shift()),
    cookie = parts.join('=');

   if (key === name) {
    // If second argument (value) is a function it's a converter...
    result = read(cookie, value);
    break;
   }

   // Prevent storing a cookie that we couldn't decode.
   if (!key && (cookie = read(cookie)) !== undefined) {
    result[name] = cookie;
   }
  }

  return result;
 };

 config.defaults = {};

 $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
  // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
  $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
  return !$.cookie(key);
 };

}));
//---------------jquery.cookie.js ends-----------
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

$j(document).ready(function()
{
  
  $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
  var myCookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
  alert(myCookie);
  
  $j('#popup_content').dialog
  (
  {
   modal:true,
   resizable:false,
   draggable:false,
   height: 525,
   width:475, 
   closeOnEscape: true,
  }
  );

});

 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) 
 {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
 }
```

I want my dialog box to open only once and I read it can be done by adding cookies to my dialog box. On searching, I got this code to add cookies to dialog box but it not working. I don't know where the error is. I am new to jquery. All I want is my dialog box should open only once.

This the entire code of jquery.cookie.js.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are getting below error in console,

> TypeError: $.cookie is not a function

If so please include the jQuery library for Cookie functions..

Please see below link for more info,

[$.cookie is not a function typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618518/cookie-is-not-a-function-typeerror)

try below code, also include jQuery dialog box related library,

```html
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"> </script>

           <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    
    $.cookie('showDialog', true); 
    alert($.cookie('showDialog'));
    
 if ($.cookie('showDialog') == undefined || $.cookie('showDialog') == null || $.cookie('showDialog') != 'false') 
  {

   $('#popup_content').dialog
   (
   {
    modal:true,
    resizable:false,
    draggable:false,
    height: 525,
    width:475, 
    closeOnEscape: true,
   }
   );
   $.cookie('showDialog', 'false', { expires: 1 }); // set the cookie, with expiry after 1 day
  }
  
  
  

 });
     
     </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Pradeep.. :)

I did download the jquery.cookie and included in the code. I don't understand where do I have to put console.

Comment: I am getting two errors.. 

1) Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function
2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cookie' of undefined

What to do?

Comment: Please share the complete code. I think you didn't included the jQuery library file as well as cookie library files.

Comment: I edited it now.. The above code works on jsfiddle fine but not on my system. What am I missing?

Comment: please try using my code which i shared above. there cookie is working. the code you shared doesn't have jquery library only.

Comment: Thank you for your patience pradeep :) I copied the code of yours and tried executing. 

I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function - main.min.js?ver=4.1.5:4

Comment: `main.min.js` js file is not at all present in my code which i gave you. How it shows that error. Whatever the code you have, mistake is there from that. Please resolve that one.