# How do I fix this jQuery conflict?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I get the error in Console that says "Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function.

I am sure this is a conflict with jQuery, but I want to know how to fix it... can someone help?

```
    // Check if cookie 
if ($.cookie("noti") !== "closed") {
   $('.dropdown-notification').addClass('active');
}

// On button click close and add cookie (expires in 7 days)
$('.close').on('click', function(){
   $.cookie("noti", "closed", { expires : 7 });
    $('.dropdown-notification').removeClass('active');
})

$('.delete-cookie').on('click', function(){
   $.cookie("noti", "open");
    $('.dropdown-notification').addClass('active');
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618518/cookie-is-not-a-function-typeerror You probably didn't include jQuery cookie library.

Comment: `$.cookie` is not built in to jQuery, it's a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie function is not in jQuery itself, you can download it here : https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few situations where this could happen.

1. Including jQuery more than once ( may seem silly, but it's happened to me more than I'd care to admit )
2. Next, and more likely, being that *$.cookie* is not a native jQuery function so you must make sure you're including that plugin as well ( after jQuery of course! )
3. My last idea, not quite as likely, sometimes the file name causes an error for reasons I can't explain. But I've seen this occur with a file named 'jquery.cookie.js' and changing it to 'jquery_cookie.js' resolved the issue in that case. Although, I can't explain why this would be a problem or how this fixes it but I've seen it work!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added a separate cookie script that was a plugin, but I seem to get that error still. Leaving me confused

Comment: Just to make sure, you have them included in the right order correct? I added to my original answer if you want to try that as well