# Cookie error in Tomcat Docker container

Tags: jquery, tomcat, cookies, war

i've imported a war inside a tomcat docker container ... but i've created this web-app on Windows, using Eclipse + Xampp (apache, mysql).

On windows all works well, on ubuntu, when i point to my first html page, when it load, there is the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.checkLoggedRedirectToLogin (manageSessionAndCookie.js:29)
    at fire (jquery-2.js:3187)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.js:3317)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.js:3536)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-2.js:3552)
```

This is my initial html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SAVA Simple Audio/Video Application</title>

    <!-- modal javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootsnip/jquery/jquery-2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootsnip/js/modal.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/manageSessionAndCookie.js"></script>

    <!-- css form login -->
    <link href="bootsnip/css/ModalLogin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Crea una nuova richiesta
    function newXMLHttpRequest() {
        var request = null;
        var browser = navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase();
        if(typeof(XMLHttpRequest) === "function" || typeof(XMLHttpRequest) === "object") {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if(window.ActiveXObject && browserUtente.indexOf("MSIE 4") < 0) {
            if(browser.indexOf("MSIE 5") < 0) {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } else {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        return request;
    }

        // Callback: è stata editata la casella di testo login_username
    function validaInput() {
        console.log ("chiamata validaInput() ajax");
        var login_name= document.getElementById("login_username");
        if (login_name.value != "") {
            var req = newXMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        gestisciRisposta(req.responseXML);
                    }
                }
            };

            var url_validate_name = getUrlServlet ("Validate_Name?email=") + escape(login_name.value);
            req.open("GET", url_validate_name, true);
            req.send(null); 
//          req.open("POST", "Validate", true);
//          req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
//          var params = "id=" + escape(ricerca.value);
//          req.send(params);
        }
    }

        // Gestisci la risposta (asincrona) dal server
    function gestisciRisposta(responseXML) {
        if(responseXML.getElementsByTagName("risposta").length > 0) {
            var risposta = responseXML.getElementsByTagName("risposta")[0];
            var output = document.getElementById("icon-login-msg");
            output.innerHTML = "";
            if(risposta.childNodes[0].nodeValue == "valido") {
                // L'id esiste
                output.setAttribute("style", "color:green");
                output.appendChild(document.createTextNode("esiste"));
            } else {
                // L'id non esiste
                output.setAttribute("style", "color:red");
                output.appendChild(document.createTextNode("non esiste"));
            }
        }
    }

    </script>




</head>





<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                    <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>  <span style="color:grey;" class="light">Using WEBRTC </span> 
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a style="color:white;" href="#" class="page-scroll" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Sign in/Sign up</a>
                    </li>     
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Intro Header -->
    <header class="intro">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <h1 style="color:grey;" class="brand-heading">  SAVA</h1>
                        <p style="color:grey;" class="intro-text">A free, interactive, modern audio/video application.<br>Created by Antonio Bosco, Pierpaolo Castellano.</p>
                        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <p>Copyright &copy; Sava 2016</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/grayscale.js"></script>




 <!--********************************************* Login and register form *********************************************-->

    <!-- BEGIN # MODAL LOGIN -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <!-- <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/logo.jpg"> -->
                    <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" src="https://secure.royalcaribbean.com/royalgifts/assets/img/icons/login-icon.png">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
                <div id="div-forms">

                    <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                    <form id="login-form">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="div-login-msg">
                                <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-login-msg">Type your username and password.</span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="login_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" onkeyup="validaInput()" >
                            <input id="login_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
                            </div>
                            <div>

                                <button id="login_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End # Login Form -->

                    <!-- Begin | Lost Password Form -->
                    <form id="lost-form" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="div-lost-msg">
                                <div id="icon-lost-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-lost-msg">Type your e-mail.</span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="lost_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button id="lost_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                                <button id="lost_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End | Lost Password Form -->

                    <!-- Begin | Register Form -->
                    <form id="register-form" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="div-register-msg">
                                <div id="icon-register-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-register-msg">Register an account.</span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="register_name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
                            <input id="register_surname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Surname" required>
                            <input id="register_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
                            <input id="register_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                            <input id="register_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button id="register_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                                <button id="register_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End | Register Form -->

                </div>
                <!-- End # DIV Form -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--********************************************* END # MODAL LOGIN *********************************************-->

</body>

</html>
```

While this is js/jquery.cookie.js:

```
/*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.1
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS
        factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    var pluses = /\+/g;

    function encode(s) {
        return config.raw ? s : encodeURIComponent(s);
    }

    function decode(s) {
        return config.raw ? s : decodeURIComponent(s);
    }

    function stringifyCookieValue(value) {
        return encode(config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value));
    }

    function parseCookieValue(s) {
        if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
            // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape...
            s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
        }

        try {
            // Replace server-side written pluses with spaces.
            // If we can't decode the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
            // If we can't parse the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
            s = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
            return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
        } catch(e) {}
    }

    function read(s, converter) {
        var value = config.raw ? s : parseCookieValue(s);
        return $.isFunction(converter) ? converter(value) : value;
    }

    var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

        // Write

        if (value !== undefined && !$.isFunction(value)) {
            options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                t.setTime(+t + days * 864e+5);
            }

            return (document.cookie = [
                encode(key), '=', stringifyCookieValue(value),
                options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
            ].join(''));
        }

        // Read

        var result = key ? undefined : {};

        // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
        // in case there are no cookies at all. Also prevents odd result when
        // calling $.cookie().
        var cookies = document.cookie ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [];

        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            var name = decode(parts.shift());
            var cookie = parts.join('=');

            if (key && key === name) {
                // If second argument (value) is a function it's a converter...
                result = read(cookie, value);
                break;
            }

            // Prevent storing a cookie that we couldn't decode.
            if (!key && (cookie = read(cookie)) !== undefined) {
                result[name] = cookie;
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

    config.defaults = {};

    $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
        if ($.cookie(key) === undefined) {
            return false;
        }

        // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
        $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
        return !$.cookie(key);
    };

}));
```

And this is js/manageSessionAndCookie.js :

```
var BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/AtApplicazione/template/';
var BASE_URL_SERLVET = 'http://localhost:8080/AtApplicazione/';
var BASE_NODEJS = 'http://localhost:8181/videoPage.html?room_name=';

/*var BASE_URL = 'http://192.168.43.159:8080/AtApplicazione/template/';
var BASE_URL_SERLVET = 'http://192.168.43.159:8080/AtApplicazione/';
var BASE_NODEJS = 'http://192.168.43.159:8181/videoPage.html?room_name=';*/

function getUrl(url) {
    return BASE_URL.concat(url);
}

function getUrlVideoChat(url) {
    return BASE_NODEJS.concat(url);
}

function getUrlServlet(url) {
    return BASE_URL_SERLVET.concat(url);
}

/*redirect to login if cookie is not defined*/
$(document).ready(
        function checkLoggedRedirectToLogin() {

            var name = $.cookie('name');

            console.log ("name:" + name);

            if(name == undefined) {
                window.location.replace(getUrl("index1.html"));
            }
});

function getEmail (){

    return $.cookie('email');

}

function getSurname (){

    return $.cookie('surname');

}
```

Why is there this error? Why there is not this error on windows (on windows i run xampp with apache and mysql started) ?

I have to tell that in Ubuntu, i've not mysql container, but also this tomcat one that hosts my war file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$.cookie is not a function typeerror](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618518/cookie-is-not-a-function-typeerror)

Comment: You have to type your keywords in Google before posting a question here. You would have found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618518/cookie-is-not-a-function-typeerror